# Getting rid of unwanted double space

Tags: spacing, hyperref, packages, indexing

After [asking a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653578/implementing-a-very-basic-index-from-scratch) on how to implement a particular basic index from scratch, I created a LaTeX package with the solution I found ([`hereapplies.sty`](https://github.com/madmurphy/hereapplies.sty)).

The usage is very simple. For example,

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hereapplies}

\begin{document}

\title{Some title}

\author{Some author}

\maketitle

This is concept one. To see this concept applied, please
see\whereapplies{conceptone}.

This is concept four. To see this concept applied, please
see\whereapplies{conceptfour}.\newpage

\hereapplies{conceptone}This is page \thepage. As you can see, ``concept
one'' applies here.\newpage

\hereapplies{conceptfour}This is page \thepage. As you can see,
``concept four'' applies here.\newpage

\hereapplies{conceptone}This is page \thepage. As you can see, ``concept
one'' applies here.\newpage

\hereapplies{conceptfour}This is page \thepage. As you can see,
``concept four'' applies here.\newpage

\hereapplies{conceptone}This is page \thepage. As you can see, ``concept
one'' applies here.

\end{document}
```

generates the following output:

[image: hereapplies package – one space example]

However there is still a bug. If you look closely, the manuscript text `please see\whereapplies{conceptone}` does not contain a space after “see”, and yet a space is added to the pdf. And if I try to add a space to the manuscript (as in `please see \whereapplies{conceptone}`), the result will contain two spaces, like in the following picture:

[image: hereapplies package – two spaces example]

How can I get rid of that unwanted double space? I would like that if I don't add a space to the manuscript the output contains no spaces either.

For completeness, I paste here the current state of my package:

```latex
%  -*- Mode: latex; indent-tabs-mode: t; c-basic-offset: 4; tab-width: 4 -*-

%
% hereapplies.sty
%
% A LaTeX package for cross-linking applications of concepts
%
% https://github.com/madmurphy/hereapplies.sty
%
% Version 0.2.0a
%
% Copyright (C) 2022 madmurphy <madmurphy333@gmail.com>
%
% **Here Applies** is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it
% under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as published by the
% Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your
% option) any later version.
%
% **Here Applies** is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
% WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
% FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Affero General Public License
% for more details.
%
% You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License
% along with this program. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
%
%
%
% Example usage:
%
%     \documentclass{article}
%
%     \usepackage{hereapplies}
%
%     \begin{document}
%
%     \title{Some title}
%
%     \author{Some author}
%
%     \maketitle
%
%     This is concept one. To see this concept applied, please
%     see\whereapplies{conceptone}.
%
%     This is concept four. To see this concept applied, please
%     see\whereapplies{conceptfour}.\newpage
%
%     \hereapplies{conceptone}This is page \thepage. As you can see, ``concept
%     one'' applies here.\newpage
%
%     \hereapplies{conceptfour}This is page \thepage. As you can see,
%     ``concept four'' applies here.\newpage
%
%     \hereapplies{conceptone}This is page \thepage. As you can see, ``concept
%     one'' applies here.\newpage
%
%     \hereapplies{conceptfour}This is page \thepage. As you can see,
%     ``concept four'' applies here.\newpage
%
%     \hereapplies{conceptone}This is page \thepage. As you can see, ``concept
%     one'' applies here.
%
%     \end{document}
%
%
\ProvidesPackage{hereapplies}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
%
%
%
%         PRIVATE ENVIRONMENT
%         ===================
%
%
% Assign a unique number to each applicable concept
\newcounter{@ha@concept@counter}
%
%
% Macro `\@ha@newapplicable{concept_name}`
% *****************************************************************************
%
% Initialize a new applicable concept
%
% Thie macro is for internal purposes only. When invoked it sets up the helper
% macros, counters and auxiliary files needed for keeping track of a concept.
% If the concept was already initialized this macro will be no op.
%
\newcommand{\@ha@newapplicable}[1]{%
    % Was this concept already initialized?
    \expandafter\ifx\csname @ha@concept@#1@cursor\endcsname\relax%
        % The concept was never initialized
        % Move the counter to the current id
        \stepcounter{@ha@concept@counter}%
        % Count unnamed occurrences
        \newcounter{@ha@concept@#1@unnamed@counter}%
        % Saved in .haN file
        \expandafter\def\csname @ha@concept@#1@output\endcsname{\textbf{??}}%
        % Last page that applies
        \expandafter\def\csname @ha@concept@#1@cursor\endcsname{-1}%
        % Store the id of the current concept
        \expandafter\edef\csname @ha@concept@#1@id\endcsname{\arabic{@ha@concept@counter}}%
        % Executes stuff in .haN file
        \@starttoc{ha\csname @ha@concept@#1@id\endcsname}%
        % Store all the occurrences when the document ends
        \AtEndDocument{%
            % Set the .haN file as the output
            \addtocontents{ha\csname @ha@concept@#1@id\endcsname}{%
                % Check that there are occurrences
                \expandafter\ifcsname @ha@concept@#1@cache\endcsname%
                    % There are occurrences - write "p./pp. ..." to the output
                    \gdef\expandafter\protect\csname @ha@concept@#1@output\endcsname{%
                        \csname @ha@concept@#1@preamble\endcsname\csname @ha@concept@#1@cache\endcsname%
                    }%
                \else%
                    % There are no occurrences - write "??" to the output
                    \gdef\expandafter\protect\csname @ha@concept@#1@output\endcsname{%
                        \textbf{??}%
                    }%
                \fi%
            }%
        }%
    \fi%
}
%
%
% Macro: `\starred@hereapplies[occurrence_name]{concept_name}`
% *****************************************************************************
%
% Equivalent to `\hereapplies*`
%
% Thie macro is for internal purposes (but nothing forbids invoking it
% directly).
%
\newcommand{\starred@hereapplies}[2][]{%
    % Make sure that the concept has been initialized
    \@ha@newapplicable{#2}%
    \ifx&#1&%
        % The macro has been called with only one argument
        % Assign a unique number to the unnamed occurrence
        \stepcounter{@ha@concept@#2@unnamed@counter}%
        % Call `\starred@hereapplies` again (recursion), but this time with 2 arguments
        \edef\tmp{\noexpand\starred@hereapplies[__unnamed\arabic{@ha@concept@#2@unnamed@counter}__]{#2}}\tmp%
    \else%
        % The macro has been called with two arguments
        % Assign a label to this occurrence
        \label{appl:#2:#1}%
        % If the cursor already points to the current page do nothing
        \unless\ifnum\csname @ha@concept@#2@cursor\endcsname=\thepage%
            % Make the cursor point to the current page
            \expandafter\edef\csname @ha@concept@#2@cursor\endcsname{\thepage}%
            % Is this the first occurrence?
            \expandafter\ifcsname @ha@concept@#2@cache\endcsname%
                % This is *not* the first occurrence
                % Use "pp." for the preamble when there are multiple occurrences
                \expandafter\def\csname @ha@concept@#2@preamble\endcsname{pp.~}%
                % Populate the cache
                \expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname @ha@concept@#2@cache\endcsname{, \pageref{appl:#2:#1}}%
            \else%
                % This is the first occurrence
                % Use "p." for the preamble when there is only one occurrence
                \expandafter\def\csname @ha@concept@#2@preamble\endcsname{p.~}%
                % Initialize the cache
                \expandafter\def\csname @ha@concept@#2@cache\endcsname{\pageref{appl:#2:#1}}%
            \fi%
        \fi%
    \fi%
}
%
%
%
%         PUBLIC ENVIRONMENT
%         ===================
%
%
% Macro: `\hereapplies[occurrence_name]{concept_name}`
% *****************************************************************************
%
% Notify the document that here a particular concept applies
%
% If the `occurrence_name` argument is passed, a new label will be created in
% the form `appl:[concept_name]:[occurrence_name]`. Without this argument the
% label created will have an opaque name.
%
% The starred version of this macro (`\hereapplies*`) will not invoke the
% `\phantomsection` directive before generating the label.
%
\newcommand{\hereapplies}{%
    % Check if a star is present
    \@ifstar{\starred@hereapplies}{\phantomsection\relax\starred@hereapplies}%
}
%
%
% Macro: `\whereapplies{concept_name}`
% *****************************************************************************
%
% Print all the applications of a concept in the form "p./pp. ..."
%
\newcommand{\whereapplies}[1]{%
    % Make sure that the applicable concept is initialized
    \@ha@newapplicable{#1}%
    % Print all the applications of the concept
    \csname @ha@concept@#1@output\endcsname%
}
```

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you. How does [that thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55246/how-to-properly-typeset-all-forms-of-punctuation-used-in-english-language-docume) help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do `\@starttoc{ha\csname @ha@concept@#1@id\endcsname}`and `\@starttoc`as well as other things does `\@input{\jobname.#1}`

it's quite hard to avoid `\input` generating a space token from at least the end of line at the end of the file but you have additional spaces from the ends of lines after `}`eg

```
\gdef \@ha@concept@conceptfour@output {pp.\nobreakspace {}\pageref {appl:concept
four:__unnamed1__}, \pageref {appl:conceptfour:__unnamed2__}}
```

as it appears you use global defs you could use

```
{\endlinechar=\m@ne\@starttoc{ha\csname @ha@concept@#1@id\endcsname}}%
```

at line 104 so that ends of lines are ignored while reading the file.

Comment: Thank you a lot, David. It works like a charm.